# Сохранение прогнозируемых данных в Dataframe

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Я смоделировал нейросеть и теперь мне нужно построит Dataframe из прогнозируемых данных.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', skiprows= 11, header=None)
Inputs = dataset[['Z', 'X', 'V', 'M']]
Outputs = dataset[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F','G', 'H']]
Inputs_arr = Inputs.to_numpy()
Outputs_arr = Outputs.to_numpy()

for i in range(0, 8):
    inputs= Inputs_arr
    outputs= Outputs_arr[:, i].reshape(-1, 1)
    
    sc = StandardScaler()
    inputs=sc.fit_transform(inputs)
    outputs=sc.fit_transform(outputs)
    inputs_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(inputs, norm='l2')
    normalizer = preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(inputs) 
    normalizer.transform(inputs)
    condition = np.isin(Inputs_arr[:,0], [125, 150])
    inputs_train, inputs_test = inputs[~condition], inputs[condition]
    outputs_train, outputs_test = outputs[~condition], outputs[condition]
    
    model= MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10), activation='relu',solver='sgd', max_iter=1000)
    model.fit(inputs_train, outputs_train.ravel())
    
    train_predict = model.predict(inputs_train)
    test_predict = model.predict(inputs_test)
    MSE = mse(train_predict, outputs_train)
    print('Training mse', MSE ) 
    MSE = mse(test_predict, outputs_test)
    print('Test mse', MSE)
    MAE = mae(train_predict, outputs_train)
    print('Training mae', MAE )
    MAE = mae(test_predict, outputs_test)
    print('Test mae', MAE)
    R2 = r2_score(train_predict, outputs_train)
    print('Train R2', R2)    
    R2 = r2_score(test_predict, outputs_test)
    print('Test R2', R2)
    print('----------------------')
```

Comment: ну так дизили, в чём проблемма то?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Я новичок и не знаю как это сделать можете подсказать?

Comment: @ganz Что такое дизил?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, я вам подсказал (привел ссылку) как задать вопрос так, чтобы его поняли другие. В текущей формулировке непонятно что у вас не получается. Кроме того непонятно как должен выглядеть ожидаемый DataFrame

Comment: А где у вас прогнозируемые данные вообще?

Answer (score 0):

После того, как вы сделали необходимое предсказание (например, на тестовом датасете), вы, вероятно, получите переменную test_predict типа `numpy array`, которую можете привести к типу `pd.DataFrame` и сохранить ее, например, в excel файл с помощью метода `to_excel()`

```
test_predict = model.predict(inputs_test)
test_predict = pd.DataFrame(test_predict)
test_predict.to_excel(*file_name*)
```

В зависимости от ваших хотелок можете предобработать датафрейм или сохранить его в другом формате (to_csv, to_json, etc)